# Jump start works, but car looses power after 1/4 mile, Battery / Alternator voltage and parts store tests fine

Tags: electrical, starting, jeep

just joined here in hope someone can guide me to solve my car problem (Jeep Liberty 2004 V6 3.7L).
Here is what happened chronologically:

1. Battery light turned on during driving
2. 3-4 days later I tested battery voltage with engine off (tested expected 12.5V with and without load). With engine on voltage increased to 14.5V and stayed there when turning on all electrical appliances. I also cleaned battery terminals with wire brush (looked pretty clean anyway no corrosion).
3. Car would not start next day (making fast machine gun like clicking sounds for as long key is turned). Jump starting worked, but car lost power after 1/4 mile drive.
4. Removed battery and alternator and got tested by parts store. Both passed test.

I am slowly getting in to fixing basic car problems so not really
    very experienced, yet. I assume somehow the battery got drained over
    time even though the alternator seems to be fine to the point car
    could not start anymore explaining why jump starting only works for
    a while. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What were the voltages *after* you couldn't start the vehicle?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will check and report once I get my own multimeter in. Had to borrow one last time.

Comment: Battery was charged in parts store. Engine turned on fine and voltages unchanged meaning 12.6 (engine off) and 14.35V at engine on. Also did voltage drop test from negative terminal to alternator body, engine block and chassis ground (all smaller than 0.05V).

Comment: The problem as stated would usually mean there's a problem with the battery. With the extra steps you've put in, it sounds as though you have a bad connection somewhere so the battery isn't being allowed to charge, or the alternator isn't getting a good voltage to setup up the field, which allows it to generate juice. I'd check the main power wire from the alternator to the battery and see if there are good connections on *both ends*. Just a suggestion, as this is a wierd problem.

Comment: Ok thanks! After doing the suggested check if you have no additional suggestions, would it be stupid to take the car for a drive and see if the battery light comes back on (meaning we're back to square 1)?

Comment: If you can take it for a drive and the light doesn't come back on, I'd keep an eye on things, but not worry about it too much.